# ImageView not showing at all in ListView with Custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I want to write a simple app that gets information from a db and displays it in rows. A textview , a checkbox and an ImageView. 
Everything works fine but it just ignores the Imageview. Is there something special to it ?

I tried using a completely empty layout with just the imageview. Still just creates an empty space. I tried using the stock android icon or other image,nothing. Using a color as background for the imageview in the empty layout seems to create a colored square area though.

any ideas?

Thanks for your time.

-- Edit

Row layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="24sp"

        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_icon"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/item_name"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/item_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="65dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="65dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_id"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

-- and this is my adapter code

```
 public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v=View.inflate(context,R.layout.item_layout,null);
        TextView raidname=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        TextView raidid=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_id);
        ImageView raidicon=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
        CheckBox status=(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.item_status);
        raidname.setText(Raidlist.get(position).r_name());
        raidid.setText(String.valueOf(Raidlist.get(position).r_id()));
        if(Raidlist.get(position).r_status().equals("alive"))
        {
            status.setChecked(true);
        }
        try
        {
            URL urlConnection = new URL(Raidlist.get(position).r_image());
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            raidicon.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //...
        }
        v.setTag(Raidlist.get(position).r_id());
        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I have not enough reputation to do a comment I ll do it this way.

Are you sure that bmp has actual data in it?

**EDIT:**
In another post I read that it could help to Scale the Bitmap while setting it

raidicon.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 120, 120, false));

Comment: Well my problem starts with the imageview it self.. not even the stock icon or images in the res directory are being displayed. But they are pretty fine in the main activity. and no,scaledBitmap method didn't work :/ ..   I appreciate your comment regardless of reputation. After all i just started learning :)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by setting resource through code. (.setImageResource...) 
thanks everyone :)